# How can I select different values in array variable,and add to another variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables

Suppose I have select something:

```
var $nodeAll = $('.sortable');
```

then I want select some from them,and add them to another variable named $node,what I want select is the parent don't have a class named 'node':

```
$nodeAll.each(function () {
        if ($(this).parents('.node').length == 0) {
            //var $node=? what should I do?
        }
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can't have more than one element with an `id="sortable"`, so I will assume that you're going to change that to a `class="sortable"`.

You use either jQuery `.filter()` with a custom filter function or you can use `.not()`.

Using `.not()`:

```
var $nodeAll = $('.sortable');
var $nodeLess = $('.node .sortable');
var $nodeFree = $nodeAll.not($nodeLess);
```

Using `.filter()` with a custom function:

```
var $nodeAll = $('.sortable');
var $nodeFilter = $nodeAll.filter(function() {
    return($(this).parents('.node').length == 0);
});
```

If you know that the `.sortable` item will never have `.node` itself, then this is a little more efficient than the previous version as `.closest()` can be more efficient than `.parents()`, but `.closest()` will look on the starting node first, whereas `.parents()` starts with the first parent and doesn't look at the current node first:

```
var $nodeAll = $('.sortable');
var $nodeFilter = $nodeAll.filter(function() {
    return($(this).closest('.node').length == 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`id`s must be unique so it makes little sense to iterate `var $nodeAll = $('#sortable')` with `each()`. Use a class of `.sortable` and instead of `each()` you could use `filter()` to reduce the collection of objects to the ones that meet a certain condition.